# Missing intermediate ssl chain fail in my nginx configuration

Tags: ssl, nginx, ssl-certificate

I have the following in my configuration file:

```
## verify chain of trust of OCSP response using Root CA and Intermediate certs
ssl_trusted_certificate /path/to/intermediate_ca;
```

My certificate is issuing *unsecure* warnings to the browser and I think it might just be because I am missing the file that presents the intermediate chain to the server. Even so, I'm using **comodo positivessl** and can't find this file after searching for it *endlessly* on ssls.com and google. Does anyone have any idea on how I should go with this? A *cipherscan* in my server issues "Certificate: untrusted" and "OCSP stapling: not supported" although I have **ssl_stapling on; ssl_stapling_verify on;** on the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the Comodo intermediate certificates [from this page](https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Default/Knowledgebase/Article/View/620/1/). Depending on when your certificate was issued, you should download either the SHA2 or SHA1.

Be sure to scroll the list and download the files associated with the PositiveSSL row in the table.

[image]

Once downloaded, combine all the files in a single .pem file:
- the server certificate (then one you received)
- the intermediates, from the most specific to the most generic

Store the file on the server and configure Nginx properly using the following settings:

```
ssl    on;
ssl_certificate    /path/to/bundle.pem;
ssl_certificate_key    /path/to/private-key.key;
```

Comment: `"Once downloaded, combine all the files in a single .pem file: - the server certificate (then one you received) - the intermediates, from the most specific to the most generic"` how exactly? I'm given an option to download either of these

`comodo-rsa-domain-validation-sha-2-intermediates.ca-bundle (4.07 KB)

 comodo-rsa-domain-validation-sha-2-w-root.ca-bundle (5.58 KB)

 comodorsaaddtrustca.crt (1.91 KB)

 addtrustexternalcaroot.crt (1.49 KB)

 comodorsadomainvalidationsecureserverca.crt (2.13 KB)`

Comment: They are text files, hence you can combine them with `cat` or any **text editor** (text editor, not Word or similar).

Comment: what is the command for this exactly? I'm sorry but you are not being detailed enough on your instructions and I'm kind of lost...

Comment: @Fane I wrote the instructions. Create a new text file that will be your certificate bundle (**use a text editor and don't use word), open the intermediate certificate files with the same editor and copy the content into the new file you created.

Comment: Simone would you mind **please** being a little more specific? I should download all those five files? And then what should I do? Create **new_file.pem** and copy paste the contents of those five files into new_file.pem? What about `cat`? Should I be doing something like `cat file_to_copy new_file.pem`?